# broken promise chaining in then callback function

Tags: javascript, promise, chaining

How to stop the promise in chaining here:

```
    .then(resp => {
      if (xxxxx) {
        return nextPromise()
      } else {
        // stop promise chain
        return
      }
    })
    .then(resp => {
       // nextPromise callback function..
    })
```

I thought the return would stop the chain but I was wrong.

Comment: throw an error or return a `Promise.reject()`

Comment: `throw 'broken'`

Comment: @Phil Don't throw strings...

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara it's just a *throw*-away comment

Comment: Kevin, at least say which `Promise` implementation do you use. Is it jQuery, Angular (and if so, 1 or 2) or something else?

Comment: @SergGr as long as it's Promise/A+ compliant, it shouldn't matter ... except older jQuery, its Promises are broken

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to break the chain by throwing an error, a solution would be to nest the chain:

```
.then(resp => {
  if (xxxxx) {
    return nextPromise().then(resp => {
      // nextPromise callback function..
    });
  }
})
```

This would still allow a global `.catch()` in which you don't have to explicitly check for an error thrown to end the chain. A drawback would be that if you have many of these conditions, you end up with something similar to ["callback hell"](http://callbackhell.com/).